# Three.js After initializing a color for a BasicMeshMaterial on an extruded shape, the color rendered to the canvas is different

Tags: three.js

I am working on an extruded shape using THREE.Shape().

When I first initialize a material for a BasicMeshMaterial I set the color to a steel blue, #4682B4. I convert it to its Hexadecimal equivalent, 0x4682B4. However, when rendered the color seems different on both Chrome and Firefox. I used a color picker on the browser (Chrome) and found the color that is rendered to the canvas to be #86B6D6.

I would like to be able to set a color and have it stay true.

To solve the issue I tried changing form using Hexadecimal colors to using RGB, 
(`color: new THREE.Color( "rgb(70,130,180)")`)
but the problem persists. I also tried several different colors, 0x07c2ff, 0x008cba. They all get shifted to a different color. Lastly, I tried using lights, but basic materials do not require them.

I am using THREE.REVISION: "107"

Here is how the shape is being created:

```
var wallShape = new THREE.Shape();
        wallShape.moveTo(0, 0);
        wallShape.lineTo(300, 0);
        wallShape.lineTo(300, 10);
        wallShape.lineTo(0, 10);

        var wallExtrusionSettings = {
            depth: 8,
            bevelEnabled: false,
        };

geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(wallShape, wallExtrusionSettings);

material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            color: 0x4682B4
        });

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material )
```

The shape renders correctly in terms of proportions and position. The only issue is the color.

I expected that the color set for the material `(color: 0x4682B4)` would be the same as the one rendered on the HTML canvas.

The actual color rendered on canvas on the browser is: #86B6D6.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Take a look at the [gammaInput and gammaOutput properties of the renderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.gammaInput)

Comment: Thank you, 2pha. I do have both of those set to true. ```this.renderer.gammaInput = true;
this.renderer.gammaOutput = true;```